How to Retrieve Active Subscriptions for a Customer in WooCommerce? REST API
I'm looking for an endpoint in the latest version of WooCommerce that allows me to retrieve a customer's active subscriptions.
I’ve tried using the following endpoint,
https://store_url.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/5/subscriptions/
but I wasn't able to get the expected results. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to properly retrieve this information?
Additionally, I'm having trouble enabling the legacy API. When I try, it redirects me to a plugin page with bad reviews. Any advice on this would also be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help
